# How to disable cascade deletion for many-to-many relations?

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

For a Many-to-Many relations (say Groups and Users) the rows from the joint table are automatically removed as soon as either of the entities is deleted, like the cascade remove attribute was set for the relation. So basically I want to delete it **IF ONLY IT IS EMPTY**. So the solution must guarantee no relations were dropped (exactly like FK constraint guarantees it).

Is it possible to not do that by default and throw an exception on foreign key constraint violation?

PS: checking before deletion is not a solution since it's a race condition prone.

PPS: mapping definitions are trivial, for the sake of completeness I post them here (even though they don't bring anything useful)

PPPS: `onDelete: cascade` is not a solution either: it creates the corresponding `ON DELETE CASCADE` on the database level.

PPPPS: `ON DELETE RESTRICT` **CANNOT BE USED** since doctrine will remove all the references from the joint table.

In roles:

```
manyToMany:
    users:
        targetEntity: UserAccount
        mappedBy: roles
```

In users:

```
manyToMany:
    roles:
        targetEntity: Role
        joinTable:
            name: user_role
            joinColumns:
                user_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            inverseJoinColumns:
                role_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
```

Comment: I assume the  `ON DELETE RESTRICT` on DB level is also not an option?

Comment: An option for what? I do not want to delete anything from a joint table.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand the initial question, but if you want to throw an exception when your try to delete rows referenced by foreign key you could set ON DELETE RESTRICT in DB. This would then simply throw an exception from DB.

Comment: @awons doctrine would remove rows from a joint table one by one, so `ON DELETE RESTRICT` will not be ever used.

Comment: Would it be replaced by one-to-many/many-to-one associations between the 3 participating classes?

Comment: @sergekv would it change anything? If yes - it might be considered as a *workaround*. But it really would be ugly, since I use other symfony2 features that require the relation to be M:N

Comment: use `ON DELETE RESTRICT`, and define a `Exception listener` till catch exception

Comment: @ghanbari `ON DELETE RESTRICT` will not be used since doctrine will remove all the relations from the joint table. If it did not - I would not even ask this question :-)

Comment: Doctrine has no cascade deleting with one-to-many by default. So you can use third class, say `Definition`, and it wouldn't be deleted by default.

Comment: @sergekv yep. But it's ugly ;-) Will wait for someone to confirm there is no good way with M:N

Comment: @zerkms, doctrine raise `[PDOException]                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails` exception as a `onDelete=restrict` is defined on relation, try `onDelete=restrict` on both `user_id` & `role_id` fields

Comment: @ghanbari if you run migrations `ON DELETE CASCADE` would be added to the joint table, which will drop those rows. `onDelete=restrict` implies you have `ON DELETE CASCADE` in the DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer can be considered as a *workaround*. The `many-to-many` association can be replaced by `one-to-many/many-to-one` associations between the 3 participating classes, because Doctrine has no cascade deleting with `one-to-many` by default.

[image: one-to-many/many-to-one]

Answer (score 1):

I came to the same problem a few hours ago:
I have a simple `ManyToMany` association between `User` and `Group` entities.

I don't want Doctrine to delete a `Group` entity if there are some related `users`, while I want Doctrine to delete a `User` even if it in some Group.

To accomplish this, in the `Group` entity I have this lines of code:

```
/**
 * Group
 *
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * 
 */

class Group
{
...
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="groups")
     * 
     */
    private $users;

...

    /**
     * @ORM\PreRemove()
     */
    public function preRemove() {
    if ($this->users->count()>0) {
        throw new \AppBundle\Utils\Exception\FKConstraintViolationException();
    }
    }

}
```

This is the FKConstraintViolationException class

```
namespace AppBundle\Utils\Exception;

class FKConstraintViolationException extends \Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ForeignKeyConstraintViolationException {
    public function __construct() {
            $message='Self generated exception';
            $driverException=new \Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\OCI8\OCI8Exception('Self generated exception.'); //or whatever driver you use if you have another db
            parent::__construct($message, $driverException);
    }
}
```

and in the controller I put the `remove()` in a `try/catch` block

```
try {
    $em->remove($group);
    $em->flush();
    $this->addFlash('success', 'deleted_successfully');
} catch (\Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ForeignKeyConstraintViolationException $e) {
    $this->addFlash('error', 'cannotdelete_related_entities');
}
```

Here is the documentation
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events

Maybe it could be best implemented creating a listener on the `preFlush` or `onFlush` event because you could actually call `remove()` on an object without flushing and you would obtain the exception.

Answer (score 1):

After bumping into the same issue and not finding any solution I spent couple hours trying to find the reason why this is happening. I'm posting my findings here for anyone else stumbling across this issue.

### In short

- Make sure `Role` is the *owning* side of the relationship
- Add `onDelete: 'restrict'` to JoinColumns. (If you're using for example symfony maker this will result in a migration with the correct ON DELETE RESTRICT)
- Add `onDelete: 'cascade'` to InverseJoinColumns. (This will prevent the data from being deleted)

Here is are example class implementations using Attributes:

```
#[ORM\Entity]
class User
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private $id;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Role::class, mappedBy: 'users')]
    private $roles;
}

#[ORM\Entity]
class Role
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private $id;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: User::class, inversedBy: 'roles')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete: 'restrict')]
    #[ORM\InverseJoinColumn(onDelete: 'cascade')]
    private $users;
}
```

### In more detail

Now I am not sure if this is how it should work, but the following findings led me to this solution:

Where it goes wrong is in the method
`Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\Entity\BasicEntityPersister::deleteJoinTableRecords()`

Specifically the condition

```
if (isset($mapping['isOnDeleteCascade'])) {
    continue;
}
```

Basically, unless this mapping is set doctrine will automatically add a query that to delete all existing entries in the relation table.

Now, where this mapping key is actually set is in the method
`Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo::_validateAndCompleteManyToManyMapping()`

This is the only place I found where `isOnDeleteCascade` is added to the mapping. This method checks both the JoinColumn and InverseJoinColumn and if either has an `onDelete='cascade'` the key is set to true. Specifically:

```
if (isset($joinColumn['onDelete']) && strtolower($joinColumn['onDelete']) === 'cascade') {
    $mapping['isOnDeleteCascade'] = true;
}
```

Unfortunately I couldn't find much information about the issue in the documentation, or if this is the intended way to deal with this issue. From what I can see, it is impossible to have a RESTRICT condition on both foreign keys the way this is currently implemented in Doctrine. But it works when only one side needs to restrict the other.